# Fun with Primes

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

FYI this is my first post on Math.stackexchange

So, I'm taking Discrete Math in University and I've just been introduced to the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. Now that I'm done my studies for the day I've been playing around with Primes trying to spot interesting patterns. One thing I noticed is that every prime number is always $2$ or $(k2^n+ 2)$ positions from the next prime. I don't think this is terribly profound because primes are by definition not even, so a prime is more likely to be odd, unless that odd number happens to be divisible by 3, or 5, or some other prime. But, I kept playing with it and I used an old C++ program to calculate the spaces between primes ranging from $1$ to $10000$. And I got this:
[And image of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlRM9.png)
The Code for this is here, in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
bool primeEval;
vector<int> prime;
int numberOfPrimes = 0;
int prev;

void PrimeSpace() {
    cout << " ";
}
int main() {
    for (int i = 2; i < 10000; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= 5000; j++) {
            int answer = i % j;
            if (i == j) {
                primeEval = false;
                continue;
            }
            if (answer == 0) {
                primeEval = false;
                break;
            }
            primeEval = true;
        }
        if (primeEval) {
            prime.push_back(i);
            if (i > 3) {
                int space = prime[numberOfPrimes] - prime[numberOfPrimes-1];
                for (int i = 0; i < space; i++) {
                    PrimeSpace();
                }
                cout << space << endl;
            }           
            numberOfPrimes++;
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, why is every prime $2, 2^n$ or $(k2^n+2)$ from the next prime and does it mean anything interesting?

Comment: Nope:  $1693 - 1669 = 24$.

Comment: 24 = 6(2^2) so it holds for the case of (k)2^n

Comment: *What*??  "... $2$, $2^n$ or $(k)2^n +2$ from the next."  Which of *these* you explicitly stated is $24$?

Comment: @David, I believe OP thinks $(k)2^n$+2 means $(k)(2^n+2)$.

Comment: It is conjectured, Westcott, that for every even number $r$, there is a prime $p$ such that the next prime is $p+r$. It's one of those conjectures that everyone believes, but no one can prove.

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  Oh gee... well if that's so, then it certainly deserves a downvote for poor $MathJax* and wasting our time.

Comment: You can probably quite easily test this hypothesis up to, say, a few million by using a more efficient prime calculation technique (such as the sieve of Eratosthenes, which you should be able to find C++ code for online, although writing it yourself could be a good exercise too).

Comment: In $k\cdot 2^n+2$, what are the values that you allow for $k$ and $n$?

Comment: "why is every prime 2, $2^n$ or (k)$2^n$+2 from the next prime" is exactly the same as "why is every prime an even number from the next prime" which is logically true

Comment: What mathematical notations are you using? I do not understand what $(k)2^n+2$ means.  Do you mean $k(2^n+2)$ instead? or is it $(k*2)^n+2$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Down voted for pure typesetting and wasting time.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The first line of the post says "FYI this is my first post on Math.stackexchange", and your response is to downvote because the poor MathJax has "wasted your time"?

Comment: 1. Not ALL primes are odd , but in fact the only even prime is $2$. 2. If you rule out $2$ , the difference between consecutive prime numbers must be even (because all primes greater than $2$ are odd) 3. Every even number greater than $2$ can be written in the form $k\cdot 2^n+2$ with odd $k$ and positive integer $n$. 4. As mentioned , it is conjectured that every even prime gap occurs infinite many often. We do however not even know whether every even prime gap occurs at all.

Answer (score 7):

This appears to be a law of small numbers situation, where a few observations reveal a pattern that does not actually hold up in general. In fact, the pattern is already shown to be broken by the code output shown, as 14 cannot be represented in any of the ways described.

What is known is that for primes $p>3$, $p$ must be congruent to $1$ or $5 \text{ modulo }6$. This means that if you take the differences between consecutive primes, they must be congruent to $0$, $2$, or $4 \text{ mod }6$. Furthermore, differences not congruent to $0$ must take you from $1$ to $5$ (diff. $4 \text{ mod }6$), or vice versa (diff. $2 \text{ mod }6$). Thus the differences will alternate between $2$ and $4 \text{ mod }6$, possibly seperated by differences of $0 \text{ mod }6$

Comment: I noticed that 14 too, but 14 is just 3(2^2)+2, hence I included (k)2n+2

Comment: But that is a good point about the congruence. So this is sort of a known pattern that I stumble on. So that's kind of neat.

Comment: @WestcottLouden Ah, I misunderstood the $(k)2^n+2$. But in that case, it simply reduces to $2(k+1)$, or any even number.

Comment: @Angelica I think that's the case here. Every prime difference not involving $2$ is an even number... and OP has defined the set of even numbers, perhaps overly so.

Answer (score 1):

$3-2=1$ is an odd difference between primes.

Your formula when $n=1$ is $2(k+2)$. As $k$ varies over all natural numbers, that varies over all even numbers greater than $2$, so you are effectively just noticing that prime differences are even when the primes are greater than 2.

Polignac’s conjecture says that every even number is a prime jump gap infinitely many times. The density of primes and their corresponding gaps can be estimated using the prime number theorem.